# How can I use LIKE wildcard in SQL if I want to search SKU starting with DE-SB and DE-TB? How does [] work here?

Tags: mysql, sql

'[abc]%' searches for words starting with a,b and c, but i want to search for two different two characters SB and TB.

The following code returns nth.

```
SELECT v.sku
FROM sylius_product_variant v
WHERE v.sku LIKE 'DE[SB,TB]%'
```

Comment: *"How can I use LIKE wildcard in SQL"* To make something clear `LIKE 'DE[SB,TB]%'` is SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax, not ANSI/ISO standard SQL syntax..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `like` twice:

```
WHERE v.sku LIKE 'DESB%' OR v.sku LIKE 'DETB%'
```

Or, a regular expression:

```
WHERE v.sku REGEXP '^DE(SB|TB)'
```